# Uninstall selected packages by date

Tags: uninstall, synaptic, software-uninstall

Is there a way to uninstall all packages that were installed in a span of time between 1 min? I tried using the synaptic package manager but I can't find any filter to be able to check only the packages that were installed at that time.

Comment: Well, I can see the time they were installed from the Ubuntu software center. The thing i actually want to know is if there is a way to select these packages(about 50 so i can't just copy their names) and uninstall them all with one click.

Comment: Yes, there is. Use the command in the previous comment and then scroll down until you get to the right time and then copy the all of the package names of the packages that you need to uninstall from the terminal into a text file so that you can uninstall them using `sudo apt-get remove <package_name-1> <package_name-2> .. <package_name-last>`.